# Modern monitor technologies - need to find a new monitor

Tags: display

I'm preparing to change my old LCD monitor for a new one. I have an old NEC 20WGX2 Pro based on an IPS panel. I'm looking for a screen that gives good color output but is very good at gaming at the same time (since it is its primary service). I tend to switch monitors between my different computers at home so it has to be multi purpose, hence IPS technology before.

Now, where can I read on newest monitor technologies so I can make an informed decision?

I need to find a best fit for myself and I have a very outdated knowledge at the moment. So *any* hints are greatly appreciated, be it info on technologies, web sources, links to other questions, etc.

Comment: As far as models go: shopping recommendations are **off-topic** as per the [Super User FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Sorry. Modified my question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an informative resource about the latest panel technologies:

http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/panel_technologies.htm

A compromise on colour reproduction / response time would be the use of a cPVA panel such as some offered by Samsung, but if you are happy with IPS technology then a safe choice would be the NEC 23" IPS panel that goes by the model name EA231WMi. I hope you find exactly what you need. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Jay. Would vote up your answer as well but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do so. I'll try to remember to post my choice when I finally make the buy decision later on (if it's not against the rules).

Comment: And I have been torn between S-IPS and S-PVA. But I will add cPVA since you say it's worthy as well. Well, going to read the provided source now.